# "names of countries" "name of country" "names of country" and "name of countries" what are the differences?

Tags: nouns

"Names of countries" - meaning names of many countries ? i.e. To list the names of countries, Brazil, Singapore, Africa, and America (is the usage correct?)

"name of country" - meaning name of one country? i.e. The name of country is Brazil (is the usage correct?)

"names of country" - meaning multiple names of one country? i.e. The names of country for America is either America or The United States?

"name of countries" - I don't know this one :D

Hope someone could explain those to me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just to do with plurals.  I shall give an explanation for each:

> names of countries

- The several names of two or more countries  - e.g. *The names of [the] countries in Eastern Europe are Lithuania, Estonia etc.*

> name of country

- **The** name of **one** country.

An example:  *The **name of** the **country** is Brazil* or, directly, *The **name of country** A is...*

> names of country

- The **several** names of **one** country.

e.g. The **names of** **the country** North America are the 'US' and 'USA'. Or, again directly: *The **names of country** B are...*

> name of countries

- One united name of several countries e.g.

*The **name of** [the] **countries** England, Northern Ireland, Scotland and Wales is 'the UK'.*

Hope this helps.